# Laravel response header only occasionally sets XSRF-TOKEN on axios.post from Vue component

Tags: php, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I have a Vue component for creating a blog post which includes an image. When it calls:

```
axios.post('/admin/blog/store', formData)
```

it occasionally works but most times I get a 419 unknown status response. I have tracked the difference between a successful post and an unsuccessful post to the fact that **Set-Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN** is missing in the response headers when I get a 419 error. Laravel throws a TokenMismatchException when I try to debug it and redirects me to the login page when I try to access the page again.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: Could you post your app.js and your bootstrap.js files?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've just got to the source of the problem. I had a couple of optional form fields that were outside of the closing </form> tag. When these were selected they were sent with the formData but the POST failed. Now I've moved them within the </form> tag all works fine.